# Question on rudin theorem 9.21

Tags: analysis, derivatives, vector-spaces, continuity, partial-derivative

[image]

[image]
[image]

I don't understand how do we get the equality: ($D_jf_i$)(x) = ($f'(x)e_j$)$u_i$

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: This math is definitely above my head, but what does $u_i$ denote?

Comment: {$e_1,...,e_n$} and {$u_1,...,u_m$} are the standard bases of $R^n$ and $R^m$. @rhkoulen

Answer (score 1):

We have

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f'(x) e_j \cdot u_i &= (\sum\limits_{k} (D_j f_k)(x) u_k) \cdot u_i \\
&= \sum\limits_k (D_j f_k)(x) u_k \cdot u_i \\
&= \sum\limits_k (D_j f_k)(x) \delta_{ki} \\
&= (D_j f_k)(x)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

using the Kronecker Delta $\delta_{ab} = 1$ if $a = b$, $0$ otherwise.

Comment: how's  the product of $u_k$ and $u_i$ is equal of $\delta_{ki}$? @Mark Saving

Comment: @vendetta If $i = k$, then $u_k \cdot u_i = u_i \cdot u_i = 1$ since the $u_i$ are unit vectors. If $i \neq k$, then $u_k$ and $u_i$ are perpendicular and thus $u_k \cdot u_i = 0$. So in either case, $u_k \cdot u_i = \delta_{ki}$.